# Using gmail gem with Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, gmail

I'm trying to use the nu7hatch/gmail gem with rails and I've run into some problems. To rule out a conflict with the rest of my app I started a new c9.io instance with an absolute minimum of code and still got the same problem. I changed the basic Rails scaffold as follows:

Gemfile (added):

```
gem 'gmail'
```

routes.rb (added):

```
root 'welcome#index'
```

welcome_controller.rb:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController
  def index
    Gmail.connect("username", "password") do |gmail|
      @emails=gmail.inbox.find(:unread)
    end
  end
end
```

index.html.erb (view):

```
<%= @emails.each do |email| %>
<p><%= email.subject %></p>
<% end %>
```

When I visit the root of my app, I get the following error:
cannot load such file -- mime/message

Rails tell me that this error refers to the line:
@emails=gmail.inbox.find(:unread)

Does anyone have any ideas how I can make this work please?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you've answered this by now or not, but I thought I would add what I found. I think the correct way to do it would be to set up something in config/initializer like what omniauth does. But I'm just using the gem for a small personal project so, I decided to build a `gmail_client` model, and tell the controller to use that.

```
//gmail_client.rb

require 'active_model'

class GmailClient
  include ActiveModel::Model

  def build
    Gmail.connect!('some_email', 'some_password')
  end

end
```

I decided to go with ActiveModel because I didn't want this sort of thing stored in a DB.

And then in the controller do something like:

```
//some_controller
...

def index
  gmail = GmailClient.new.build
  @emails = gmail.inbox.find(:unread)
end

...
```

Comment: Oh, this actually needs some retooling. Because you're opening a connection every time, Gmail will block after 15 requests.

To prevent this, you'll want to add `gmail.logout` after the requests.